# How long to leave Kathmandu airport

Tags: visas-on-arrival, kathmandu

It is my first time flying abroad, and I will actually be doing it alone. I am flying to and from Adelaide (Australia) to Kathmandu.

I have a question on how long it takes to "leave" Kathmandu airport upon arrival, taking into account that I will also need to get a visa on arrival.

Thing is, I am going to Kathmandu for a school trip, where I have to meet at a hotel (20 minute drive from Kathmandu airport) approximately 3 and a half hours after the claimed arrival time of my flight. So essentially, I have three hours to "clear" the Kathmandu airport. Is this sufficient?

Thank you!

Comment: For a normal airport this should be more than enough time.

Comment: And presuming your incoming flight is not delayed...